# Ошибка next-auth beta, next-js 14.0.3 Error: NEXT_REDIRECT

Tags: auth, nextjs

При создание логина на сайте возникла проблема с ошибкой Error: NEXT_REDIRECT, ни как не могу понять от куда она берется и как её пофиксить, установленные пакеты:
"next": "14.0.3",
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.4",

Суть в том что если я пытаюсь при логине, или выходе отловить ошибку try catch то получаю ошибку Error: NEXT_REDIRECT а если без неё, тогда все работает.

код.

Мой middleware я создал костюмную функцию переадресации.

```
//middleware.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [],
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async authorized({ auth, request }) {
            const isLoggedIn = auth?.user;
            const isOnDashboard = request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
            console.log('auth:', auth, 'isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn, 'isOnDashboard', isOnDashboard)
            if (isOnDashboard) {
                if (isLoggedIn) return true;
                return false;
            } else if (isLoggedIn) {
                return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.nextUrl));
            }
            return true;
        },
    },
}).auth;

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)'],
}
```

В своём auth.js я выполняю подключение к дб, проверку если пользователь, и возвращаю его если данные верные.

```
//auth.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { connectToDB } from "./lib/utils";
import { User } from "./lib/models";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const login = async (credentials) => {
    try {
        connectToDB();
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: credentials.username });

        if (!user || !user.isAdmin) throw new Error("Wrong credentials!");

        const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
            credentials.password,
            user.password
        );

        if (!isPasswordCorrect) throw new Error("Wrong credentials!");

        console.log('user login', user);
        return user;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to login!");
    }
};

export const {
    handlers: { GET, POST },
    signIn,
    signOut,
    auth
} = NextAuth({
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async authorized({ auth, request }) {
            const isLoggedIn = auth?.user;
            const isOnDashboard = request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
            console.log('auth:', auth, 'isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn, 'isOnDashboard', isOnDashboard)
            if (isOnDashboard) {
                if (isLoggedIn) return true;
                return false;
            } else if (isLoggedIn) {
                return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.nextUrl));
            }
            return true;
        },
    },,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    const user = await login(credentials);
                    console.log('user authorize', user);
                    return user;
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('authorize error:', err)
                    return null;
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.username = user.username;
                token.img = user.img;
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (token) {
                session.user.username = token.username;
                session.user.img = token.img;
            }
            return session;
        },
    },
});
```

Теперь я пытаюсь выполнить логин через try catch

```
//login
<form action={async (formData) => {
    "use server"
    console.log('Начало 1');

    try {
        await signIn("credentials", formData)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}} className={styles.form}>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" />
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

В таком случае я получаю ошибку Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
полная ошибка

```
Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
    at getRedirectError (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:44:19)
    at redirect (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:54:11)
    at signIn (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:62:89)
    at async $$ACTION_1 (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/ui/login/loginForm/loginForm.jsx:74:9)
    at async D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:489
    at async tX (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:37:5313)
    at async rl (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:23339)
    at async doRender (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1406:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1567:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1475:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1852:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1890:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:902:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:266:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (D:\Person\Edvard\Desktop\nextadmin\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:798:17) {
  digest: 'NEXT_REDIRECT;replace;http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard;false',
  mutableCookies: p {
    _parsed: Map(8) {
      'wordpress_test_cookie' => [Object],
      'wp_lang' => [Object],
      'wordpress_logged_in_86a9106ae65537651a8e456835b316ab' => [Object],
      'wp-settings-time-1' => [Object],
      'PHPSESSID' => [Object],
      'authjs.csrf-token' => [Object],
      'authjs.callback-url' => [Object],
      'authjs.session-token' => [Object]
    },
    _headers: HeadersList {
      cookies: [Array],
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    }
  }
}
```

При этом логин срабатывает! Я обновляю страницу и попадаю в уч. запись, то есть логин сам работает а редирект нет.

А если я делаю без try catch вот так

```
//login
<form action={async (formData) => {
    "use server"
    console.log('Начало 1');

    await signIn("credentials", formData)

}} className={styles.form}>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" />
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
);
```

То логин тоже срабатывает, и так-же переадресация тоже срабатывает.

Не знаю в чем может быть проблема, если использую try catch для отлова ошибок как в официальной документации

```
import { AuthError } from "next-auth"
import { signIn } from "../auth"

export default function Layout() {
 return (
   <form action={async (formData) => {
     "use server"
     try {
       await signIn("credentials", formData)
    } catch(error) {
      if (error instanceof AuthError) // Handle auth errors
      throw error // Rethrow all other errors
    }
   }}>
    <button>Sign in</button>
  </form>
 )
}
```

То получаю ошибку, а если не использую все норм, ошибка пропадает....